# Create script in package.json to remove duplication

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have inherited a project with some e2e test commands in the package.json file that are a bit messy.  For the most part the commands are the exact same thing minus the final command in the list that determines whether to run in browser or headless modes.  Is there a way to tidy this up to prevent duplication?

This seems to work fine - It's just not ideal to maintain.

```
"scripts": {
  "test:cafe": "testcafe",
  "test:cafe-headless": "testcafe chrome:headless",
  "test:e2e": "concurrently --kill-others --success first 'npm run dev' 'wait-on http://localhost:8080/admin && wait-on http://localhost:8081/health && npm run test:cafe'",
  "test:e2e-headless: ": "concurrently --kill-others --success first 'npm run dev' 'wait-on http://localhost:8080/admin && wait-on http://localhost:8081/health && npm run test:cafe-headless'"
}
```

My thought was to split the duplication out into its own command.  But as soon as the setup command runs, it kills the server, so my tests cannot run.  Is there a way for me to keep it alive?  Or am I doing something wrong?

```
"scripts": {
  "test:setup": "concurrently --kill-others --success first 'npm run dev' 'wait-on http://localhost:8080/admin && wait-on http://localhost:8081/health'",
  "test:cafe": "testcafe",
  "test:cafe-headless": "testcafe chrome:headless",
  "test:e2e": "npm run test:setup && npm run test:cafe'",
  "test:e2e-headless: ": "npm run test:setup && npm run test:cafe-headless'"
}
```

Thanks